# What are the prerequisite concept for implementing A* in SDL?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, artificial-intelligence, conceptual

I need to make simulation app where i need to move one object from one point to another point in the presence of other objects.

So my question is what are the concept should i need to learn for making implementation.

Comment: graph or bitmap? 2D/3D? what constrains? be more specific... look here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23779490/2521214 and here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29749599/2521214

Comment: @Spektre Graph,2D....Sounds very complicated....

Comment: A* on 2D or 3D grids (bitmaps) are easy and reliable. The graph versions are a bit more complicated and there are MANY questions about them here on SO (I had no reason to  use graphs in my programing yet so I cant help there) There are also another approaches like using Fields (attractive/rettractive) The concept is that you need to represent your cognitive map of environment (graph or image or voxel map or set of vectors/objects ...) Then update it time to time, and search for partial/full path in it to drive the object(s ) is this multiagent or single path, also are obstacles moving?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28317199/2521214 the Backtracking section to see how grid A* works (it is really simple) ...

Comment: @Spektre ya that was catchy.......I will try to implement......